# $f_*\mathcal{F}$ is quasi-coherent if $\mathcal{F}$ is quasi-coherent and $f$ is affine

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, affine-schemes, quasicoherent-sheaves

> Let $f:X\to Y$ be an affine morphism of schemes. Prove that if a sheaf of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules $\mathcal{F}$ is quasi-coherent, then $f_*\mathcal{F}$ is also quasi-coherent.

I think the first natural idea is to take the exact sequence

$$\bigoplus_{i\in I}\mathcal{O}_X\big|_U\to\bigoplus_{j\in I}\mathcal{O}_X\big|_U\to\mathcal{F}\big|_U\to 0$$

and apply the direct image $f_*$ so that

$$\bigoplus_{i\in I}f_*\mathcal{O}_X\big|_U\to\bigoplus_{j\in I}f_*\mathcal{O}_X\big|_U\to f_*\mathcal{F}\big|_U\to 0$$

I've tried without success to prove that $f_*\left(\bigoplus_{i\in I}\mathcal{O}_X\big|_U\right)=\bigoplus_{i\in I}f_*\mathcal{O}_X\big|_U$. Maybe a finiteness condition (or something) is needed, but I can't see how $f$ being affine would guarantee
 that.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can assume that $Y$ is affine. Then?

Comment: @Diego, actually we may suppose both $X,Y$ are affine, right? I still can't see how I'm supposed to use this

Comment: If your $f$ is $Spec(A)\to Spec(B)$ and $\mathcal{F}=\tilde{M}$ for an $A$-module $M$, then, who is $f_*(\mathcal{F})$?

Comment: Some advice: when you fail to tag algebraic geometry questions with the tag algebraic-geometry, you will get and fewer views and you are thus less likely to get an answer. If you are interested in getting answers to your questions related to algebraic geometry, I would recommend applying the tag.